# Autoexpand option in Olingo Odata Java

Tags: java, odata, olingo

It seems that we need to have $expand in the request URL to include the navigationset data in the response. Do we have any option to auto expand the nvaigationset?

I can see this option available in Microsoft OData library but could not find any way to do this in Olingo OData v4 Java.

Comment: can you elaborate how its available in Microsoft OData library. You can use `$expand=*` in OData4

Comment: check this [link](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-15-autoexpand-attribute) for Microsoft OData library. I want to use something similar in Java as I do not want my clients to add $expand=* in URL to expand some of the navigation properties.